# Modelisation of relational data

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, relationship

I'm new to web development, and I would like advises of more experienced developers.

I have to modelise a basic relational system.

I have 3 type of data.

> **USERS**
>   **DESIGNS**
>   **PROJECTS**

**USERS** have 0 - N **DESIGNS**
**USERS** have 0 - N **PROJECTS**
**PROJECTS** have 1 - 1 **USERS**
**PROJECTS** have 1 - N **DESIGNS**

Basically the **USER** can have a list of **DESIGN** and **PROJECTS**.
And a user will associate one **DESIGN** to a **PROJECT**.

My question is: What happens if a user want to remove a **DESIGN**?
It will basically remove the design from the list,
But what happen if a project has a relation with the same design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Has" means nothing. You have to tell us *what the relationships are* that involve values representing entities and their attributes. Eg for a relationship/table with attributes/columns for user U and project P, *how* they are related, ie what rows go in the table. User U works on project P? User U is disgusted with project P? Users on project P are not permitted to work on design D? Users on project P *are* permitted to work on design D? You have to make it so clear that a person updating the database can take every possible row that *might* go in a table and be able to tell by looking at the current business situation whether it *does* go in the table.

That's all you need to know to update and query the database. Updaters look at the current situation and keep the tables holding the rows of values that are related according to each relationship.

Given *what the relationships are* and *what situations can arise*, generally *only certain combinations of table values can arise*. Eg if a table holds the rows where "project P produces design D" and a design is only ever produced by one project then there will only ever be one row with a given D value in the table. Whereas if a design can be produced by multiple projects then that won't be the case. Eg if "project P produces design D" always implies that "D is a design", then if you "want to remove a design" d from the second table then you *must also want* to drop the rows that look like (P, d) from the first table. It would be an *error* if they weren't requested dropped at the same time. Whereas if the second table is for "design D is stupid" then dropping a design from it might might be independent of other tables. But remember, you don't need to know constraints to update & query.

We write constraints to tell the DBMS to reject as errors requests for updates to database states that cannot arise. Eg a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint to say that every row has a unique D value in the case above. Cardinalities are just *some* information about a relationship, identified so we can tell the DBMS about restrictions on what *pairs* of table values can come up. Eg a FOREIGN KEY constraint to say that every D in the "first" table above must appear as a D in the "second". But remember, constraints follow from knowing *what the relationships are* and *what situations can arise*.

Also, since we frequently want to update multiple tables involved in a FOREIGN KEY constraint at the same time, SQL DBMSs allow CASCADES to be associated with them. This allows us to concisely & declaratively express things like that if a referenced row is DELETEd then all the referencing rows should be DELETEd too.